# Contradiction of the extension of the electric field of a charge to infinity

Tags: energy, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, information

The usual point of view is that the electric field is distributed to infinity and the information about displacement of a charge translates to every other charge in the universe with the speed of light. It seems obvious to me that for this information transfer as well as for the displacement to every other charge is needed an infinite amount of energy. How to explain this phenomenon or what is wrong in the presumption of the infinite amount of needed energy?

Comment: Obvious?  Why so?

Comment: @garyp From this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410664/

Comment: Hi holger, would be unfair to you to say that you are putting too much emphasis on being able to actually measure any quantity placed at infinity, (by definition you can't??:) Also, even ignoring this (to me, strong) objection, can the expansion of space, dark energy, be completely ruled out as a contribution to your hypothetical measurement. Just curious, best regards.

Comment: @Countto10 “being able to actually measure any quantity placed at infinity, (by definition you can't??:)” That is the point, we defined fields to influence charges up to infinity, but this is A theory only. Another theory would be that fields consist of quanta (two quanta) and fields are with finit influence. To think about the structure of fields would leading to a deeper understanding of matter and space.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler thanks for the reply, it taught me a lot about my assumptions.

Comment: @Countto10 Black humor or how to understand? Sorry for my question

Comment: @HolgerFiedler no humor  (or offence of any kind) intended) Holger, I assumed continuity, I shouldn't have. I don't know enough to, intentionally at least, insult anyone. Sorry for the unclear comment,  I genuinely learn from your questions, and upvoted this one earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this information? The volume integral of the field energy of a charge converges like $r^{-1} $ for large distances. It picks up its value at small distances and diverges for a point charge. As to radiation, any emitted photon may reach an atom very far away but with a probability dropping off as $1/r^2$.no infinite energy involved there either.

Comment: From your answer it follows that the electric field is not continuous but discrete?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems obvious to me that for this information transfer [...] is needed an infinite amount of energy.

This is because you've misread your [source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410804). The energy density of the electromagnetic field,
$$
\frac{\mathrm dU}{\mathrm dV} = 
\frac12 \left(
\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac1{\mu_0}B^2
\right),
$$
contains *exclusively* the fields, and none of their derivatives. There is nothing in this expression for the energy that would require "infinite amount of energy" for the transfer of information (which would require terms in time or space derivatives of the fields).

The electromagnetic energy cited above *does* have the problem that the  *total* amount of energy integrates to infinity for a point electric charge, as one integrates over the volume immediately around the point charge, and this is indeed a problem with the classical electromagnetic theory. (Basically, you can discard this 'self-energy' by hand, but that cannot be done in a Lorentz covariant way.) This problem is solved within quantum electrodynamics via the theory of renormalization; if you want to have a cogent conversation about the solution to that infinite-energy problem, then a strong mathematical grounding in QFT is a non-optional requirement.