# Why is electrostatic force a function of the product of charges, not the sum?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, coulombs-law, superposition

When you have two forces , you ADD them to get the total. If both of us push on a car, the total force on the car is the sum of our forces. But, If we have an electron approaching another electron, the force between them is given by Coulomb's law:

f=k q1 * q2 / r^2

How does one derive this formula from first principles? And why is it not the sum of q1 and q2?
The first flaw in this argument is that the electrons have a spherical electric field in 3d space. Their sum would only be valid in one dimensional space.
Consider two electrons in Abbot's world named 'Flatland' for simplicity's sake. Now imagine that the electric field of each electron is a circle.
 [electron](https://ibb.co/fmQM78)

Imagine a force vector,F which we can break down into x and y components like so:

[vectors X and Y](https://ibb.co/eFFSfT)

Fx = cos(A) * F

We can calculate the Total force to the right by integrating from -pi/2 to pi/2 like so:

[total force to the right](https://ibb.co/e6PQZo)

= F*2

Now imagine another electron to the right. It too has a bunch of force vectors whose x component we can calculate

All the horizontal components that will interact with another electron to the right will be the sum of all Fx so we integrate from -pi/2 to pi/2. Its total will also be F*2

So the sum of all forces pushing the electrons apart is F *4.
or Q * 4

not Q ^ 2

I could extend this argument to 3 space but it still does not give Q ^ 2.

Comment: A single electron has an electric field not a force field around it so it doesnt make sense to say an electron outputs force. But i think it was empirically determined to be proportional to the product of charges, also with a linear addition two equal but opposite charges will experience no force and this is clearly not the case

Comment: Take a charge 1 with $q_1$. It is affected by another charge $q_2$ according to the Newton equation with the force in it $\propto q_1\cdot q_2/r_{1,2}^2$. If you want to calculate the force from these two charges on a third charge, it will be a sum $\propto q_3(q_1/r_{1,3}^2+q_2/r_{2,3}^2)$. The sum of charges may be obtained if $q_1$ and $q_2$ stay at the same place and act on a third charge.

Comment: You’ll be very hard-pressed to find any non-empirical argument for why the electromagnetic interaction isn’t linear with the charge (which is what you’re asking) in the realm of classical electrodynamics; I imagine there may be some deeply mathematical argument in QED, though.

Comment: I like to think of the [energy stored in the fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/410804/44126), where the motion of the charge is a side effect of the evolution of the field.

Comment: Aghostinthefigures gets what I am asking. I am looking for a fundamental explanation of WHY we should use the product of charges in the numerator of Coulomb’s law. Consider the denominator of Coulomb’s law. There is a clear geometric explanation for the use of radius squared. Given a static charge, then the total charge energy is the same no matter where u are relative to the charge. The charge density however is equal to the charge divided by the surface area of the surface at a given distance. Thus the inverse square law is “derived” from first geometric principles

Comment: My own feelings parallel the model builders who postulate extra dimensions in the area of string theory to explain behaviors of particles seen in collider. Basically they invoke more dimensions. Similarly, I would propose that that charges interact in more dimensions than we perceive. Then the forces would add up through more dimensions and the magnitude would be greater than simply the sum.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or telling us. This should be put on hold.

Comment: I don't get where you're going with the argument about forces, but what is the conceptual difference between $F_x$ and the "total force to the right"?

Answer (score 4):

> why is electrostatic force a function of the product of charges, not the sum?

Stipulate that $q_2$ is zero, i.e., that particle 2 is electrically neutral (*uncharged*).

If the electric force between the two particles is proportional to the *product* of their charges, then the electric force between an electrically charged particle and an electrically uncharged particle is *zero*.

However, if the electric force between the two particles is proportional to the *sum*, there would be an electric force between an electrically charged particle and an electrically uncharged particle.

Which model better fits what is actually observed?

---

UPDATE:

From a comment by the OP:

> I am looking for a fundamental explanation of WHY we should use the
>   product of charges in the numerator of Coulomb’s law

It still isn't clear to me what you're looking for.  In your question, you open with an example of adding forces together to get the total force and then use this to question why the product of the charges is used in the Coulomb force law.  But this seems like a category error to me.

Consider the case that there are *three* charges.  The *total* electric force on one of the charges *is* just the sum of the Coulomb force due to each of the other charges.  Similarly, and in reference to your opening paragraph, the total force on the car is the *sum* of each individual's pushing force.

On my view, the use the car example as a legitimate motivation for seeking the "fundamental explanation" for the product in Coulomb's law is just plain confused.

---

From another comment by the OP:

> Yeah I guess your logic clearly works. But I might counter with the
>   argument that there really is no uncharged particle.

Even if one were willing to entertain that objection, one can stipulate that $q_1 \gg q_2$ and then you have the result that the electric force between the two charges is (effectively) independent of $q_2$.

Again, which model better fits what is actually observed?

Comment: Yeah I guess your logic clearly works. But I might counter with the argument that there really is *no* uncharged particle. Even atoms have an electron cloud. Though the net charge is zero, the electron cloud will have an effect on an adjacent electron at close distances. Still I see your point but it is not a derivation that illustrates Coulomb’s law from first geometric principles

Comment: @aquagremlin, I quoted the title question and that is what I addressed.  Yes, you may reject that initial stipulation and assert that there are no electrically uncharged particles.  And, at that point, I confess the *fact* that I've completely lost interest in what you might have to say.  Shall I delete my answer?

Answer (score 2):

We can possibly apply this logic.

Due to superposition, the force the first charge applies to the second charge should be proportional to the value of the first charge, i.e., doubling the value of the first charge should double the force, etc.

For the same reason, the same should be true for the force the second charge applies to the first.

Since it is essentially the same force (third Newton's law), it has to be proportional to the values both charges.

Comment: Don’t know what you mean by superposition. But in the context of your first statement I would ask “why should the force be proportional”. Why not just the sum. It is a fundamental question whose answer will tell us HOW fields interact.

Comment: @aquagremlin Superposition is a fundamental principle, which, if applied to this case, says that force exerted by two electrons on a charge is equal to the sum of forces exerted by each electron acting alone, which means that it would be twice greater. For three electrons, it will be 3x, etc., i.e., force will be proportional to a number of electrons or magnitude of charge. In your example, force on the car would be proportional to a number of people pushing the car. Multiplication, after all, comes down to adding something multiple times.

Comment: now you really lost me. you said "force exerted by two electrons on a charge is equal to the sum of forces exerted by each electron acting alone". Doesnt that mean we SHOULD sum the charges of two electrons and not multiply them?

Comment: @aquagremlin Please read to the end and take time to think about it: Multiplication = adding multiple times.

Comment: "Doubling" isn't the best choice, since $2\times 2 = 2+2 $.

Answer (score 2):

A lone point charge, $q_1$, makes an electric field with a magnitude that is proportional to the charge (at fixed $r$):

$$ {\vec E} = \frac {q_1} {4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$$

The force on a charge, $q_2$, in an electric field is proportional to both the charge and the field:

$$ {\vec F} = q_2{\vec E} $$

So I think you can see where I'm going: the force between 2 charges:

$$ {\vec F} = \frac {q_1q_2} {4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$$

thus goes as the product of the charges.

Comment: Thank you Jeb. But I guess I am asking for WHY is the force proportional to the charge and the field - why is the force not equal to the sum of the magnitudes of the charge and the field.

Comment: @aquagremlin I was afraid of that. My argument is tautological since the field is force per unit charge. If you write the force as a sum, can you find a logical inconsistency?

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot simpler than I think you are making it out to be.

Suppose the force on some $q$ due to some other $Q$ is $f.$ What would it be for twice the charge, $2Q$?

Well if superposition is to hold—in other words if the universe behaves in the simplest way—then the answer must be the same as “what is the force from two charges $Q$ each a hair’s breadth apart?” and the answer must be $f+f,$ or $2f.$ For $3Q$ we would get $f + f + f = 3f$. In general $nQ$ must lead to the force $nf$ for natural $n$.

One can immediately extend this to rational $r$ by reasoning backwards, or counterfactually: whatever the force from $Q/2$ is, call it $\varphi,$ and then realize that the earlier charge $Q$ is twice this and so by the foregoing argument that force is $f = 2\varphi$ hence $\varphi = f/2.$ From there one has reals as things which admit successive rational approximations, only the obvious extension of $rQ$ having force $rf$ works OK with being rationally approximated.

The $q Q$ approach is the only way to guarantee this multiplicative scaling and also Newton’s third law.

Comment: I am somewhat baffled. You said "the answer must be f+f".   Doesnt that mean we SHOULD sum the charges of two electrons and not multiply them? There is no a priori reason that the force between q and Q should double if you double Q. It could simply be q+Q+Q. I dont mean to be dense, but consider this comparison. I have two eggs in one basket and three eggs in another. All together they weigh 5 egg units (Sorry I dont mean to involve gravity but it too has an almost identical force law) If I double the eggs in one basket to 6, I then have 8 egg units,(2+6), not 12 (2x6).

Comment: @aquagremlin Maybe it helps if we do not talk about charges but cars. Imagine that you have a big concrete block you are dragging through a parking lot with one car, and you want to double the car’s “strength,” whatever that means. The most reasonable meaning you can assign would follow the principle of superposition: a car is twice as “strong” if it does the same thing as two cars side by side pulling the block independently. This directly causes the force on the block to have a form proportional to the car-strength by the above arguments.

Comment: Now it's true that there is a family of other definitions of car-strength, in fact one could say that with some reference car’s strength $s_0$ any other strength $s$ could be fed into any monotonically increasing function $f$ to get a new definition $f(s/s_0)$ which in some sense measures the car’s strength in some different way. I don't think you can get this to make the overall form look like $q+Q$ when accounting for Newton’s third law but you could certainly try. But the easiest way is to use the force exerted by charges to define their magnitude of charge, and that is what SI units do.

Comment: In fact I can tell you the first big mathematical problem with $q + Q,$ which is that there is no convenient way to refer to an uncharged particle. In order to satisfy the requirement that the force on an unchanged particle $q$ is zero independent of $Q$ one has to assign it a value such that $q + Q$ is independent of $Q$, a value which does not change under addition of a constant. One might therefore impose $q=-\infty$, but this makes it very hard to recover $0$ for the force.